# A difficult construction of a 3-dimensional matrix in numpy from a 2-d one

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to get the following 3-d matrix using numpy's optimiziations (without using `for`). The matrix's formula is:

[image]

Using `for` loop, it would write something like:

```
Y[i,c,a] = y[i,c] * (a == c) - y[i,c] * y[i,a]
```

where the size of the `a` index is the same as that of the `c` index, an the `i` index is different. For general knowledge, the above formula is the derivative of the softmax function `y[i,a] (x[i,c])` w.r.t to a matrix element `x[i,c]` in a batch operation.

How can I  write the function `f(y)` that returns `Y` as above?

Comment: Could you show us a loop based solution?

Comment: What is `\delta`? Do you want a function in Python that returns `Y` given the indices `i,c,a`? Is `y` a three-dimensional matrix and `Y` a scalar?

Comment: try opening braces with Kronecker delta and processing two cases separately

Comment: 1. A loop based solution is actually what I wrote above.
2. `\delta` is the Kronecker delta, `y` is 2d, and `Y` is 3d.
3. Opening braces doesn't help me, as even the first additive I can't find a way to write efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one option using broadcasting and slicing.

```
def f(y):
    Y = -y[:,None]*y[:,:,None]
    m,n = y.shape
    Y.reshape(m,n*n)[:,::n+1] += y
    return Y
```

Comment: How do you handle the Kronecker delta?

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks.

Comment: @Joe last but one line. Merging the "c" and "a" axes and then striding with step n+1 selects the diagonal which is also what the Kronecker delta selects.

Comment: Magic, I like it :)

Answer (score 0):

## Using `for` loops

So if I am understanding it correctly, using `for` loops would yield something like:

```
# Define dummy matrix dimensions
i = 3
a = 4
c = a

# Init the matrices with adequate dimensions
y = np.random.rand(i,c)
d = np.random.rand(a,c)
Y = np.zeros([i,c,a])

for ii in range(i):
    for ic in range(c):
        for ia in range(a):
            Y[ii,ic,ia] = y[ii,ic]*d[ia,ic] \
                      - y[ii,ic]*y[ii,ia]
```

## Not using `for` loops?

However, it does not seem possible to me to do it without any `for` loop. If you consider the first term of the expression, it represents the element-wise multiplication between lines of y and delta. For instance, for given `i` and `a`: `Y[i,:,a] = y[i,:]*d[a,:]`, where `*` is the element-wise multiplication. So this requires at least:

```
for ii in range(i):
    for ia in range(a):
        Y[ii,:,ia] = y[ii,:]*d[ia,:]
```

We still need to deduce the second part of the equation. Here, for given columns `c` and `a` of y, `Y[:,c,a] = y[:,c]*y[:,a]`. And adding this final operation:

```
for ic in range(c):
    for ia in range(a):
        Y[:,ic,ia] = Y[:,ic,ia] - y[:,ic]*y[:,ia]
```

This yields the same result as using the three initial `for` loops.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, you're still using for loops (an two of them). I can do it in one: 
`Y = np.empty((*y.shape, y.shape[1]))`, then `for i in range(y.shape[0]):`, `Y[i] = y[i] * np.eye(y.shape[1]) + y[i] @ y[i].T`, `return Y` (I can write it only line by line in the comment).

But it lacks optimizations in the most important axis (i).

Comment: CORRECTION: the line inside the for loop is `Y[i] = y[i] * np.eye(f_out.shape[1]) - y[i] * y[[i],:].T`